# Review two branches

Tags: git, plugin-fugitive

**description**

I like the *fugitive* `:Git` to review uncommitted code.

I would like to do same between branches + uncommitted code. Basically to locally review MR or PR.

From *fugitive* there are `:Gclog` and `:Gclog --` which are almost ok. But very very slow to bootstrap. And which are not that practical.

**question**

Ideally I really would like the `:Git` output from my current code state against `master`.

Is there some solution with or without *fugitive*?

Comment: What's wrong with just `:!git diff`?

Comment: Have a look at the various `:Gdiff` options.

Comment: @Matt `:!git diff mybranch` give the terminal result to a `vi` buffer as a `less`. But it is far from the interactive list like `:Git`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble [`:Gdiff` as been moved to `:Gdiffsplit`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/doc/fugitive.txt#L686). It work for a file from *the current state* against *the previous commit*. I want an **overall overview interactive list** of my files against *a specific branch*. What does `:Git` but specifying a branch.

Comment: Then do `:read !git diff` to get output into Vim's buffer. Or `:read !git show COMMIT:FILE` to get individual object and then `:diffthis` by Vim's internal differ against any other loaded buffer. In fact, any "git plugin" is a piece of Vimscript code working on top of `git` tool.  And they all do it the same way. Just a bit of syntax highlighting and local-to-buffer keybindings to make it look prettier.

Comment: ok `:read !git diff` is a good hint. However `:read !git diff --name-only master` looks more as the list I am looking for in the first place. Overall subject is still the same at this point I would like an easy way to open a *git diff* and unfortunately `:diffthis` does not do the job.